# dplyr doesn't evaluate column name given tailored function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Dplyr inside tailored function doesn't evaluate column.

I spent hours to figure out the problem in the code. I have a dataframe (example below) that has several columns and created the function below to pass dataframe and column. The goal is to do filtering and mutate to do linear interpolation. However, the function doesn't read the argument column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(imputeTS)
library(zoo)

dfm <- tbl_df(data.frame(country=rep('BGD', each=48), year=c(1970:2017), 
       STUNT=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,                                                                 
       70.9,    NA, NA, NA, 63.4,   73.6,   71.5,   69.2,   67.3,    
       65.8,    63.8,   59.7, 59.3, 59.9,   50.8,   53.2,   51.4,   47.8,    
       50.5,    45.9,   45.1,   43.2,NA,    NA, NA, 41.4,   42,  
        38.7,   36.1,   NA, NA, NA, NA)))


vari = "STUNT"


data_impute<-        function(data, vari) {

                 data %>% 
                 select(country, year, paste0(vari)) %>%
                 group_by(country) %>% 
                 filter(seq_along(vari) >= min(which(!is.na(vari))) &
                        seq_along(vari) <= max(which(!is.na(vari)))) %>%
                mutate(vari= na.interpolation(vari, option="linear")) %>%
                select(country, year, paste0(vari)) %>%
                 ungroup()
               }
```

when execute the function with data, instead it gives column STUNT with string "STUNT". I see the dplyr operation inside doesn't evaluate the column from the group_by to end. I have read many other similar posts but none helpd. I would be grateful if you can advice where is the problem.

Comment: Where does `na.interpolation` come from? If from a library, please include at the top so others can run your code.

Comment: you can just index the variable in any number of ways `(grep("vari", names(data))` or `which(names(data) == "vari")`

Answer (score 1):

https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-why-how.html

`dplyr` uses a form of "non-standard evaluation" which is very convenient in many cases, but makes for more work when you want to use it for programming. I think the code below works, except for the `na.interpolation` function from another package, presumably. The approach I took was to "quote" the variable up top, then use the !! ("bang bang") operator to unquote where needed.

```
data_impute<-        function(data, vari) {
  vari_quo <- enquo(vari)
  data %>% 
    select(country, year, paste0(!!vari_quo)) %>%
    group_by(country) %>% 
    filter(seq_along(!!vari_quo) >= min(which(!is.na(!!vari_quo))) &
             seq_along(!!vari_quo) <= max(which(!is.na(!!vari_quo)))) %>%
    # skipped next line b/c I don't have na.interpolation function
    # mutate(!!vari_quo := na.interpolation(!!vari_quo, option="linear")) %>%
    select(country, year, paste0(!!vari_quo)) %>%
    ungroup()
}

data_impute(dfm, vari)
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I just found a solution that works. This is the use of !!rlang::sym(vari).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `!!rlang::ensym`. This accepts arguments as literal or string.

```
data_impute<-function(data, vari) {

  data %>% 
    select(country, year, !!rlang::ensym(vari)) %>%
    group_by(country) %>% 
    filter(seq_along(!!rlang::ensym(vari)) >= min(which(!is.na(!!rlang::ensym(vari)))) &
             seq_along(!!rlang::ensym(vari)) <= max(which(!is.na(!!rlang::ensym(vari))))) %>%
    mutate(vari := na_interpolation(!!rlang::ensym(vari), option="linear")) %>%
    select(country, year, !!rlang::ensym(vari)) %>%
    ungroup()
}

> head(data_impute(dfm, vari = STUNT))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  country  year STUNT
  <fct>   <int> <dbl>
1 BGD      1985  70.9
2 BGD      1986  NA  
3 BGD      1987  NA  
4 BGD      1988  NA  
5 BGD      1989  63.4
6 BGD      1990  73.6

> head(data_impute(dfm, vari = "STUNT"))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  country  year STUNT
  <fct>   <int> <dbl>
1 BGD      1985  70.9
2 BGD      1986  NA  
3 BGD      1987  NA  
4 BGD      1988  NA  
5 BGD      1989  63.4
6 BGD      1990  73.6
```